# How to access data from an array by index for repeated items in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs. I have a home view displaying **ng-repeated** student names. When you click each name, it has to display that student's details.

[image]

However, when I click each name, the view doesn't display details for that particular student.

[image]

Here is my home view:

```
<a ng-href="#!/info/{{$index}}">        
    <div class="info" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: order | filter:expression">
        <div class="img">
            <img ng-src="{{user.image}}">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h3 style="color: #007acc;"> Student Details For:</h3>
            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is my info view:

```
<div class="text" style="padding: 0 5%;">
    <p><span>Name:</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{info.name}}</p>
    <p><span>Room:</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{info.room}}</p>
    <p><span>Cell:</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{info.cell}}</p>
    <p><span>Guardian Cell:</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{info.nokcell}}</p>
    <p><span>Guardian Email:</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{info.nokemail}}</p>
    <br>
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        controller: "mainController",
        templateUrl: "views/home.html"
    })
    .when("/info/:id", {
        controller: "infoController",
        templateUrl: "views/info.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    })
});
var data = [
{
    name: "   Andrea Toe",
    room: 12,
    cell: "0724884888",
    nokcell: "0724884975",
    nokemail: " ",
    image: "images/female.jpg"
},
{
    name: "Relebogile Maile",
    room: 3,          
    cell: "07248844322",
    nokcell: "24 Old Pretoria Rd, Midrand",
    nokemail: " ",
    image: "images/female.jpg"
},
{
    name: "Siyabonga Ntshangase",
    room: 1,
    cell: "0753284888",
    nokcell: "0853884888",
    nokemail: " ",
    image: "images/male.jpeg"
}
];

app.controller("mainController", function($scope){
 $scope.users = data;
});

app.controller('infoController', ['$scope', 'users', '$routeParams', function($scope, users, $routeParams) {
  users.success(function(data) {
    $scope.info = data[$routeParams.id];
});
}]);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$index` is only reachable from inside the ng-repeat.

Move the ng-repeat to the a-tag instead

```
<a ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: order | filter:expression" ng-href="#!/info/{{$index}}">        
    <div class="info">
        <div class="img">
            <img ng-src="{{user.image}}">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h3 style="color: #007acc;"> Student Details For:</h3>
            <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

You should then set the `$scope.info` directly when the controller is loaded instead of waiting for the success function from `'users'` (what is that?)

Try it like this

```
app.controller('infoController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.info = data[$routeParams.id];
}]);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MthandazoDube updated the answer. U need to remove the users dependency which you inject but don’t register anywhere

Comment: I have done it but the info view doesn't load at all. I don't know where im getting it wrong. maybe something is wrong with my routeProvider.

Comment: Thank you Marcus, I finally got it to work, you are a life saver.

Comment: @MthandazoDube please upvote and accept answer then :)